# Не выводится сообщение после анимации

Tags: javascript

Почему таким образом не выводится сообщение после анимации ?

```js
  function go() {
    showCircle(150, 150, 100).then(div =>{
       div.classList.add('message-ball');
       div.append("Hello, world!");
    });
  }

  function showCircle(cx, cy, radius) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.width = 0;
    div.style.height = 0;
    div.style.left = cx + 'px';
    div.style.top = cy + 'px';
    div.className = 'circle';
    document.body.append(div);

    setTimeout(() => {
      div.style.width = radius * 2 + 'px';
      div.style.height = radius * 2 + 'px';

      div.addEventListener('transitionend', function handler() {
        div.removeEventListener('transitionend', handler);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        resolve(div);
      })
      });
    });
  }
```

```css
 .message-ball {
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 200px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .circle {
      transition-property: width, height, margin-left, margin-top;
      transition-duration: 2s;
      position: fixed;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      background-color: red;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
  <button onclick="go()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function go() {
  showCircle(150, 150, 100).then(div => {
    div.classList.add('message-ball');
    div.append("Hello, world!");
  });
}

function showCircle(cx, cy, radius) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.width = 0;
  div.style.height = 0;
  div.style.left = cx + 'px';
  div.style.top = cy + 'px';
  div.className = 'circle';
  document.body.append(div);

  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      div.style.width = radius * 2 + 'px';
      div.style.height = radius * 2 + 'px';

      div.addEventListener('transitionend', function handler() {
        div.removeEventListener('transitionend', handler);
        resolve(div);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.message-ball {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  transition-property: width, height, margin-left, margin-top;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="go()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: скажите пожалуйста почему ошибку кидает ?

Comment: @Leks Потому что Ваша `showCircle` ничего не возвращает.

Comment: я правильно понял что  в моем примере функция setTimeout возвращает в showCircle  промис а showCircle  ничего не возвращает и таким образом ошибка ?

Comment: @Leks Нет. Во-первых, `setTimeout` возвращает идентификатор таймера (целое число) и все. Во-вторых, `showCircle` у Вас "возвращает" `undefined`, от которого вызывающий код пытается вызвать `then`.

Comment: понял спасибо за пояснения